# Running 2 database querys from an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run 2 database querys the second using an array from the first, any one have any ideas why this stops the page from loading?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM listings WHERE listing_id = '1' LIMIT 1");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT listing_title FROM listings WHERE listing_type =     '".$row->category_id."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    foreach ($query2->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->listing_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make your question a little clearer? What does "won't run" mean?

Comment: Well it dosnt actually throw up an error, the view I am editting it on just stops the page from loading.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? This IS still in a class isn't it? The code looks right. The answer looks right. More code might be useful here.

Comment: Hmm... This looks like a method of a class. Can you post the class too.

Comment: I believe I may have found a solution which doesn't require to take into account what's above or below the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the outer $row in your inner loop

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM listings WHERE listing_id = '1' LIMIT 1");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT listing_title FROM listings WHERE listing_type =     '".$row->category_id."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
    foreach ($query2->result() as $row2) // <--- $row2 not $row
    {
        echo $row2->listing_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed this but still no luck

Comment: is the for each allowed inside the foreach, when I remove the middle one my code works? Is there maybe a better way for me to do this?

Comment: foreach rows are allowed within foreach loops.

Comment: @SimonStaton Not really, this is the most logical way. How many results does $query2 give?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(Take advantage of prepare statements, the prepare() function, etc)

```
$query = "SELECT category_id FROM listings WHERE listing_id = '1' LIMIT 1;";
$query2 = "SELECT listing_title FROM listings WHERE listing_type = :categoryId ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;";

$db = $this->db;

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $statement->fetch())
{
    $categoryId = $row['category_id'];

    $statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->execute(array(':categoryId' => $categoryId));
    $statement2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row2 = $statement2->fetch())
    {
        $listingTitle = $row2['listing_title'];
        echo $listingTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very good code. Why use a `foreach` loop when the Select query has `Limit 1`?

Since you are going for a category id where listing_id=1 (with LIMIT 1), your code could just be shortened to:

```
SELECT listing_title FROM listings WHERE listing_id=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Also, `ORDER BY RAND()` is a big resource killer on large tables. I recommend finding a more proper way to order your results.

EDIT: Full code that I would use:

```
$db=$this->db; //Just so we don't have to keep referencing $this (assuming you are not in a class)

$sql="SELECT listing_title 
FROM listings 
WHERE listing_id=? 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2";

$statement=$db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(1));

while($result=$statement->fetchObject()){
    echo $result->listing_title;
}
```

Comment: " Why use a foreach loop when the Select query has Limit 1?" I suppose he only want 1 results meanwhile he's testing.

Comment: True, but since he failed to mention his overall goals with his project, I will assume the code speaks for itself.

Comment: Yes, what you're saying is correct. I just hope that my answer solves his problem.